# Regex for remove rules of css in js

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to remove some css rules from a string with regex

exactly i want to remove all rules that have ":hover"
for example body:hover

so i need to remove string between ","  that contain :hover in something like this string

```
.hovered,.showFrame .container-fluid .added-element:hover , #MR_Modal_View.showFrame .container-fluid .added-element:hover , .showFrame .container-fluid:hover, #MR_Modal_View.showFrame .container-fluid:hover, .added-element:hover, body , div.test , #MR_Modal_View_Modal .added-element:hover, .ui-resizable-resizing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex you can do it. My suggestion is to use a three step approach. Split the text into lines, catch the text you want, and join the strings again:

```
var text = ".hovered,.showFrame .container-fluid .added-element:hover , #MR_Modal_View.showFrame .container-fluid .added-element:hover ,.showFrame .container-fluid:hover,#MR_Modal_View.showFrame .container-fluid:hover,.added-element:hover, body ,div.test , #MR_Modal_View_Modal .added-element:hover, .ui-resizable-resizing";
text = text.replace(/,/g,'\n').replace(/.*:hover\s*\n*/g, "").replace(/\n/g,',');
```

How this [regex works](https://regex101.com/r/dP2fD9/1)
Look this [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nchLq4cz/1/)

Comment: Thanks . but this regext only work in this exmaple , i edited my question and put new css rules, it dosent work well

Answer (score 0):

You don't **have** to use a regex for this. The following code spits your string into an array of classes, filters the ones that do not contain `:hover` and converts them back to a string.

```
var classes = ".hovered,.showFrame .container-fluid .added-element:hover, #MR_Modal_View.showFrame container-fluid .added-element:hover ,.showFrame .container-fluid:hover, MR_Modal_View.showFrame .container-fluid:hover, .added-element:hover, #MR_Modal_View_Modal added-element:hover,.ui-resizable-resizing";

var filteredClasses = classes.split(',')
   .filter(function (c) { 
     return c.indexOf(':hover') === -1; 
   })
   .join(', ');

console.log(filteredClasses) // prints ".hovered,.ui-resizable-resizing"
```

Comment: as it is a huge app , i need the best performance , so i think regex

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to match CSS rules for different browsers (compatible problems),

I found this lib may help to remove/add/change rules:

https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj

It's render CSSOM from JS into `<head>`, and you can change rules directly from JS Object.